# How to customize the length of text field in dialog box?

Tags: dialog

When I want to save a file from a website and choose "Save As" in whichever browser I'm using, a dialog box pops up, allowing me to choose the place and name under which to save the file.

The text field containing the file name, however, is rather short, showing just about 50 characters, and it remains so even if I increase the width of the "Save As" dialog box (see picture included). This is somewhat of a nuisance when dealing with long file names.

Is there any way to customize the length of this text field?

I am running Ubuntu 18.10.

[image: "Save As" dialog box with increased width but narrow "Name" text field]

Comment: Pluma, when run in Ubuntu Mate 18.10 has a name box wide as can be. Pluma, when run in Ubuntu  18.10 has the width restrictions you describe. Leafpad, a gtk2 application, is unrestricted in this way in Ubuntu 18.10. So, it seems that there's something at play **in Ubuntu 18.10**  affecting gtk3 applications in the manner you describe.